# Linux record live to cd

Tags: linux, audio

Is it possible to record an audio input source in Linux directly to a CD?

I am a DJ and currently I use my laptop AUX in with Audacity to record my sets. After the set, I need to split the audio into multiple parts (80min), export, then burn to CDs to listen to in the car. This takes a lot of time (my laptop is quite old) and I really don't need a digital recording on my drive. I only listen to them to hear my faults and correct myself during the next play.

What I would like to set up is a Linux box with a decent sound card and 2 cd drives. I would then start playing, the computer would start recording to disc 1. When disc 1 is full it would switch to disc 2 and pop disc 1 out so I can put in a fresh disc.

Is something like this possible under Linux (with Python perhaps?). If someone knows of an application that would do this under Windows or Mac I'm interested in it too, but I'd like to stick with Linux if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt it. CDs are written at a constant speed, much faster than the sound playback (a few minutes vs some hour and a half). Write to disk (or an USB drive), and write it to CD later.